# Unexpected exception: Compilation failed on new Play project

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am getting this error on freshly created Play 2.1.3 application. I am running Java 7u25. I created new application and ran it with "play run" from within application directory.

```
Unexpected exception
Compilation failed without reporting any problem!?
No source available, here is the exception stack trace:
->sbt.compiler.CompileFailed: 
     sbt.compiler.JavaCompiler$$anon$1.compile(JavaCompiler.scala:59)
     sbt.compiler.JavaTool$class.apply(JavaCompiler.scala:26)
     sbt.compiler.JavaCompiler$$anon$1.apply(JavaCompiler.scala:51)
     sbt.compiler.JavaCompiler$class.compile(JavaCompiler.scala:17)
     sbt.compiler.JavaCompiler$$anon$1.compile(JavaCompiler.scala:51)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$compileJava$1$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply$mcV$sp(AggressiveCompile.scala:83)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$compileJava$1$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:83)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$compileJava$1$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:83)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.sbt$compiler$AggressiveCompile$$timed(AggressiveCompile.scala:101)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$compileJava$1$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(AggressiveCompile.scala:82)
     sbt.classfile.Analyze$.apply(Analyze.scala:85)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$compileJava$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(AggressiveCompile.scala:81)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$compileJava$1$1.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:81)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$compileJava$1$1.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:81)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.sbt$compiler$AggressiveCompile$$timed(AggressiveCompile.scala:101)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4.compileJava$1(AggressiveCompile.scala:80)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:88)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:60)
     sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:24)
     sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:22)
     sbt.inc.Incremental$.cycle(Incremental.scala:45)
     sbt.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:29)
     sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:20)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile2(AggressiveCompile.scala:96)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile1(AggressiveCompile.scala:44)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:31)
     sbt.Compiler$.apply(Compiler.scala:79)
     sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:572)
     sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:572)
     sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf2$1.apply(Structure.scala:578)
     sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf2$1.apply(Structure.scala:578)
     scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
     sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
     sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
     sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:41)
     sbt.std.Transform$$anon$5.work(System.scala:71)
     sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
     sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
     sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
     sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:238)
     sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
     sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
     sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
     sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
     java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't use JDK 1.8? Also which version of SBT, and which version of scala are you using? I had something similar to this happen and have experienced a few failures (albeit usually with some form of error reporting).

My solution was use SBT version 0.13.15 or 1.0.3

You can specify your SBT build version in your /project/build.properties file

```
sbt.version=0.13.15
```

Also might try using scala version 2.11.8, I've found it to be pretty rock solid! (You can set this in your build.sbt file)

```
scalaVersion := 2.11.8
```